# How do I get a PC to output at 120hz signal to a 120hz TV?

Tags: display, hdtv, refresh-rate

Asking this on behalf of a friend of mine who just recently got a 120hz TV.

My friend has a Westinghouse LD-4055 - he has a PC with an NVIDIA GTX 560 Ti and fairly modern midrange parts.

He's trying to get his PC to output at 120hz in 1080p resolution for 2D purposes (intends to use it as a second monitor).  However, the Display control panel and the NVIDIA control panel is still locking him in at 60 Hz.  He tried forcing 120 hz but the TV is still saying it's a 60 Hz signal.

Is it impossible for him to do so or is there some sort of step he's missing?  I read a few posts saying how the TV won't really do 120 Hz and will just take a 60 Hz input from the PC and double it, or something along those lines, but even when the PC is outputting a 60 Hz signal, the refresh rate on the TV remains at 60 hz.

What does he have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that HDMI or single link DVI even has the bandwidth for 1080p/120hz.

The purpose of 120hz TVs isn't to accept 120hz signals, it's to double (or quintuple, in the case of a 24hz signal) the framerate of the incoming signal to reduce perceived motion blur and judder.

Answer (score 1):

I have an NVIDIA 560 Ti and a Vizio M602i-B3 (2014 model). It *can* output 120 Hz to the TV via HDMI - but only at 720p or below.

You can change the refresh rate in the NVIDIA Control Panel. Under "resolution", my GPU supports selecting 120 Hz when the resolution is 1280 x 720.

If you can't do this, the TV may not be compatible.